# "Swift Core Data" and UISearchController

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, uialertcontroller, uisearchcontroller

I have a `tableView` with `NSFetchedResultsController`! I have fully completed `NSFetchedResultsController`'s delegate methods and works perfectly! My problem line is presenting a `UIAlertController`. `UIAlertController` works well on the `tableView`, but doesn't works inside of the `UISearchController`. I'm attempted to delete objects inside of the `UISearchController`. When I press a delete button Xcode gives me error like so:

[image: <code>2016-03-05 07:37:42.456 UISearchController[8289:180216] Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x7ff7a046f740> on <UISearchController.MainTableViewController: 0x7ff7a2919240> which is already presenting (null)</code>]

Here's codes of my `commitEditingStyle` method and `UIAlertController`, `UIAlertAction`'s `handler`:

`// Override to support editing the table view.
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {

```
        let itemToDelete:Manager = self.fetchedResultsController.objectAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! Manager
        prepareForDelete(itemToDelete)

        // Delete the row from the data source
        //tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)
    } else if editingStyle == .Insert {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }    
}

// Delete Action
var itemsToDelete:Manager!

// Delete function
```

private func prepareForDelete(managedObject:Manager) {

```
    //
    self.itemsToDelete = managedObject

    // Alert
    let alert:UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Warning!", message: "Do you want to delete this note?", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)

    // Actions
    let deleteAction:UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Delete", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Destructive, handler: deleteHandler)

    // Actions
    let cancelAction:UIAlertAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel, handler: nil)

    // Add actions to the alert
    alert.addAction(deleteAction)
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)

    // Present alert
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func deleteHandler(alert:UIAlertAction) -> Void {

    // Delete from the moc
    if let delete = self.itemsToDelete {
        self.managedObjectContext.deleteObject(delete)
        do {
            // Save changes
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {

        }
        self.itemsToDelete = nil
    }
}`
```

How to disable `UIAlertController` ? I do not need alerts inside of the
 `UISearchController`. Because this function doesn't work inside of `UISearchController`

Thanks for your attention!

Comment: So if you are searching you don't want the alert to pop up - no deleting?

Comment: I want to delete objects with alert on the `tableView`! It works well. But I can't delete objects inside of the `UISearchController `, when `UISearchController ` is active. I need alerts on `tableView`, outside of the `UISearchController `! But I do not need inside of this.

Comment: Thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if your search controller is active (I'm assuming you have a reference to your search controller in the view controller).

Add this to the beginning of `prepareForDelete`:

```
guard !searchController.active else { return }
```

That code checks if the search controller is not active, but if it is, it doesn't execute any code.

Comment: Ok! I'll try it... Thanks again.

Comment: It seems to works! But delete option has been disabled, when `searchController` is active. I need an alert in `tableView` . I do not need an alert inside of `UISearchController`. Both cases are must deletable with an `alert ` ( `tableView` ) and without an `alert ` ( `searchController` ) respectively.

Comment: @AmateurUser I'm afraid I don't have enough information about how to delete without an alert. You need to tell me how you want it and try it out first.

Comment: I found! I have changed `commitEditingStyle` method! And works perfectly now. Thanks of your help.